# Slow performance in mongodb compound geospatial index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collections called "location" one of which documents look like :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5726ad18bdb861058819ea00"),
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -90.426407,
            34.850685
        ]
    },
    "name" : "restaurant name",
    "tags" : [
        "Chinese",
        "thai",
        "American",
        "indian"
    ]
}
```

and i have the following index :

```
db.location.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "chatx.location"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "loc" : "2dsphere",
            "tags" : 1
        },
        "name" : "loc_2dsphere_tags_1",
        "ns" : "chatx.location",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

i used tags to identify restaurant food type types.

I have been trying to find out nearest restaurants based on food(s) type. My query is :

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "location",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-90.426407, 34.850685] },
     limit:10,
     maxDistance:5000,
     spherical: true,
     query: { tags:{$all:["chinese", "thai"]}}
   }
)
```

In order to do that i used $geoNear (which is very good performative in 3.2 version ). However when i combine with tags (using $all) , query then becomes slower, which makes sense, because $all searches all the documents based on first element then refines based on other elements. The main reason for a query becomes slower is increasing limit (e.g: 10 to 100 or more) and array elements["thai", "indian", .....]. For example if i search restaurants with 4 food type tags, query becomes super slow rather than if i search restaurants with 1 food type tags.

I was wondering if anybody can help me either figuring out best schema for this collection or providing better query options.

Comment: Be sure to create an index for the coordinates you're storing. Apart from that, ``$all`` shouldn't be slow since it's working on the tags and this should be a relatively small list.

Comment: I have a compound index like : "name" : "loc_2dsphere_tags_1",

Comment: yes is slow (15second for 2mln record query - kind of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227548/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-search-engine/40264031?noredirect=1#comment67954807_40264031

Comment: Daniele Tassone, I have improved the query performance using 1) Multikey index 2) limiting the number of documents and 3) setting the maximum and minimum distance.