# how to use mongoDB as a search engine?

Tags: mongodb

I try to use mongoDB as a search engine and realize that it's a disaster. i try do do simple query against 5 millions geo located documents.

```
db.runCommand( { dropDatabase: 1 } )

db.createCollection("places"); 

db.places.createIndex( { "locs.loc" : "2dsphere" } )


function randInt(n) { return parseInt(Math.random()*n); }
function randFloat(n) { return Math.random()*n; }

for(var j=0; j<10; j++) {  
  print("Building op "+j);
  var bulkop=db.places.initializeOrderedBulkOp() ;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    bulkop.insert(    
      {
        locs: [
          {
            loc : { 
              type: "Point", 
              coordinates: [ randFloat(180), randFloat(90) ] 
            }
          },
          {
            loc : { 
              type: "Point", 
              coordinates: [ randFloat(180), randFloat(90) ] 
            }
          }
        ]
      }  
    )
  };
  print("Executing op "+j);
  bulkop.execute();
}
```

and then i run a query that match no documents :

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: { category: "xyz" }
   }
)
```

it's take **4 minutes** to return !

```
   "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
   "results" : [ ],
   "stats" : {
           "nscanned" : 10018218,
           "objectsLoaded" : 15000000,
           "maxDistance" : 0,
           "time" : 219873
   },
   "ok" : 1
```

the same query made on for exemple somethink like sphinx index (that use in fact no index at all for such query, it's just scroll all the reccord that are already in memory to filter them) return in **200 ms**

what i do wrong? their is 32GB of memory free on the computer and all the data use only 150 MB. Is their any way to speed up mongoDB? or definitively we can't use mongoDB as a search engine ?

Comment: remove "query", on my computer I can get 6ms on 1mln record.

Comment: { "nscanned" : 117, "objectsLoaded" : 59, "avgDistance" : 0.001017138667266944, "maxDistance" : 0.0016776194783600408, "time" : 2 }

Comment: Daniele, thanks, but the purpose is exactly to not remove "query" :( because before to run a query you don't know if it's will match some records or not ... here the idea was to simulate a query that return no (or very few) records. and 4 min to see that their is not corresponding record is not acceptable

Comment: you should have an Index then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MongoDB 3.4rc with 2mln records**

I think the problem with your code is related to the 'query' param, because you are making another query on a Collection without an index.

**UPDATE (with results/stats):**

```
db.runCommand( { dropDatabase: 1 } )

db.createCollection("places"); 

db.places.createIndex( { "locs.loc.coordinates" : "2dsphere" } )


function randInt(n) { return parseInt(Math.random()*n); }
function randFloat(n) { return Math.random()*n; }

for(var j=0; j<10; j++) {  
  print("Building op "+j);
  var bulkop=db.places.initializeOrderedBulkOp() ;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    bulkop.insert(    
      {
        locs: [
          {
            loc : { 
              type: "Point", 
              coordinates: [ randFloat(180), randFloat(90) ] 
            }
          },
          {
            loc : { 
              coordinates: [ randFloat(180), randFloat(90) ] 
            }
          }
        ]
      }  
    )
  };
  print("Executing op "+j);
  bulkop.execute();
}
```

[image: Collection (i have more object, since i run the script more then once]

This is the query:

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true
   }
)
```

**58ms:**
[image]

**2ms second run:**
[image]

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: { category: "private" }
   }
)
```

**156996ms:**
[image]

After creating "category" index:
{ locs.loc.coordinates: "2dsphere", category: 1 }

**13562ms:**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
by adding "maxDistance" you can perform **396ms** vs **6863ms**

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: {category: "private"},
     maxDistance: 1000000
   }
)
```

maxDistance: 1000000

```
"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : NumberInt(107820), 
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberInt(1), 
    "avgDistance" : 938598.1782650856, 
    "maxDistance" : 938598.1782650856, 
    "time" : NumberInt(396)
}
```

without "maxDistance":

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: {category: "private"}
   }
)

"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : NumberInt(2023916), 
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberInt(6), 
    "avgDistance" : 3013587.205365039, 
    "maxDistance" : 4263919.742779636, 
    "time" : NumberInt(6863)
}
```

Source:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/geospatial-performance-improvements-in-mongodb-3-2

Even more your query is using "an array of coordinates" that I think is useless since one object (generally) has 1 geolocation point.

Another way to optimise is making "**geoWithin**" since is not sorting by "distance" (maybe you want to sort by "most voted restaurant"). Depending from the scenario.

Comment: just see my previous comment, the purpose is exactly to not remove "query" :( because before to run a query you don't know if it's will match some records or not ... here the idea was to simulate a query that return no (or very few) records. and 4 min to see that their is not corresponding record is not acceptable

Comment: you should have an Index then

Comment: but i can't add index on all possible query ! on sphinx their is no index and it's take 200 ms to return

Comment: @loki can you really explain what you want to do and then update your question? What your question look like is a "massive query that prove MongoDB is slow on Geolocalization query": this is not true as you can read from my answer. Now you are asking to have a query/schema that work on all the scenario you want without using Index. I think your request should be well written.

Comment: ok, so try to run this query: db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9667, -40.78 ] },
     spherical: true
   }
) ... it's will take also some minutes to return :(

Comment: I have already try and it take some seconds. I will update the question.